# NativeScript 8.1 migration: adding external to webpack.config.js

Tags: webpack, nativescript

I'm in the midst of migrating a large NativeScript 6.8 JavaScript project to NativeScript 8.1.  My current obstacle is adding a service to the new webpack.config.js.  Here's the lines from the old file:

```
appComponents.push(...[
        "tns-core-modules/ui/frame",
        "tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity",
        resolve(__dirname, "./app/foreground-service.android.js"), // <-- this is the addition
    ]);
```

I've read through the [referenced documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/webpack) several times but am not understanding how to specify this in the new webpack config.  I'd welcome any insights.

For context, see this [Nativescript-geolocation issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation/issues/256).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the new webpack in ns8 to build a your custom service, write your webpack.config.js like this:

```
const webpack = require('@nativescript/webpack')

module.exports = env => {
  env.appComponents = (env.appComponents || []).concat(['./src/app/foreground-service.android'])
  webpack.init(env)

  return webpack.resolveConfig()
}
```

More on webpack config for ns8 see
https://docs.nativescript.org/webpack.html#webpack-chainwebpack-chainfn-options and
https://docs.nativescript.org/advanced-concepts.html#extending-android-activity

Comment: Thanks!  This works, with one correction.  The path to the service is outside the /app folder, so the line becomes: env.appComponents = (env.appComponents || []).concat(['./foreground-service.android'])